# How to generate current_timestamp() without timezone in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to get the current_timestamp in a column in my dataframe. I am using below code for that.

```
df_new =  df.withColumn('LOAD_DATE_TIME' ,  F.current_timestamp())
```

But this code is generating load_date_time in below format when exported to csv file.

`2019-11-19T16:59:44.000+05:30`
I don't want the timezone part and want the datetime in this below format.

`2019-11-19 16:59:44`

Comment: use parameter `timestampFormat` while creating csv

Comment: there is a keyword argument `timestampFormat` where you can specify how timestamp should be written while writing to CSV. Check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv)

Comment: need to specify while reading the csv? or we can specify while writing the file to csv as well...?

Comment: you can do it in both.. check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dateformat#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv)